# Can not gmail login in android version lollipop handleSignInResult:false

Tags: android, integration, google-plus-signin

When i try to signin with google plus it's give me activityResultfalse in some android device version above 4.4.

```
public class SignInActivityWithDrive extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Views
    mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]

    // [START customize_button]
    // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
    // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
    // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
    // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
    // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
    // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
    // difference.
    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    // [END customize_button]
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Comment: I had same error before few days. Check your google json file you got from google developer site. And put it in root folder of app.

Comment: i put it but not working